# MySQL Database different insert

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

From my server, I create and execute a query to my database. The query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`attr`) 
VALUES (
  'myText',
  ...
);
```

Insert works fine, but when the myText is (for example) the `€` character, it inserts `â‚¬` (ISO representation). When I execute a query inside phpMyAdmin with this character, **it works**. Could somebody tell me where is the problem?

NOTE: in `PHP`, `myText`, which is inserted into a query, is `€` - so it´s not converted to ISO representation before the query.

UPDATE: I use MySQL 5.5

UPDATE 2: I have `CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin` on my table.

Comment: which platform you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after mysql connection, before any query, use this:

```
mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db(...);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

from then on, you can use queries and utf8 chars will be displayed properly.

UPDATE:

Don't forget to put `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in your document.

Comment: I´d like to ask one additional thing about your solution. Where to put this `meta` tag, if I have object-oriented architecture? Before all `require`s in my `index.php`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it´s not necessary to put there also `<meta>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to encode the string..

```
$myText = utf8_encode('MyText');

INSERT INTO `table`(`attr`) 
                      VALUES (
                      '$myText',
                      ...
                      );
```

Comment: Is that needed? In phpMyAdmin, there is no encoding necessary

Comment: phpmyadmin puts in the data in the right encoding. Notice in phpmyadmin you can also see what encoding each ROW has, if you click a table and pick the Structure tab. Under Collation

Comment: After utf8 - encoding I come to this value: `Ã¢Â‚Â¬`

Comment: @Tom11 That looks like double encoding, I might have been wrong on the encoding then. Is the $mytext generated while visiting a webpage with PHP? Please also make sure your charset decloration in HTML is set to UTF8, and then don't encode the message like I did above.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

Answer (score 0):

checkout the `charset` and `collations` of your `table` [charset documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html)

Comment: `CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin`
I don´t think there is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySql server is not expecting UTF8 by default, run the following query first

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Comment: I have `CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin` on my table.

Comment: `SET NAMES` has nothing to do with table charset, it tells the server which charset the client is sending.

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin probably has charset configured properly for connection, but your script doesn't.

Make sure you have [configured charset correctly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) for example by statements:

```
SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF-8';
SET NAMES 'UTF-8';
```

Before pushing anything to DB (if you're using `latin1` instead of `UTF-8` as your table charset, you should use `latin1`).